# RMarkdown slidy presentation: tabset?

Tags: r, r-markdown, slidy

I am looking for a way to use {.tabset} in an RMarkdown Slidy presentation, but the tabs are not created and it just lists everything sequentially on the slide. Does anyone know if it is possible to do this?

```
## High-level summaries {.tabset}

### Specific summary 1

### Specific summary 2
```

Answer (score -1):

tabset option is currently available for HTML document only. This option may not available for slidy presentation. More at https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1324

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).